# Any best practices with feedback colours?

Tags: user-interface, colors, user-feedback

I have a few that I think are correct. These are background colours for messages.

- ERROR: red;
- INFO: blue;
- SUCCESS: green;
- NOT IMPORTANT INFO: yellow

Have I got the blue and yellow around the wrong way? Any hex values that are a de facto standard for these?

I am curious considering web development, but I think the answers will be agnostic.

Here is an interesting thought (I'm sure I've read about it in an article). What colours would the errors be on [Target's website](http://www.target.com/), considering all their branding is red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are pretty much straightforward. For non-important info, I don't if a yellow would be good since it's usually interpreted as "warning" or "look-here!".

I would be inclined to go for a gray or maybe a tan colour (like Windows default tan colour). A non-alertful colour.

Answer (score 2):

### It's important to understand there are no 'right' colors.

For instance, this could be 'correct' within an existing interface that is designed in a particular way:

- ERROR: yellow/black;
- INFO: grey;
- SUCCESS: blue;
- NOT IMPORTANT INFO: beige

**So this kind of question makes designers wince:**

> "Have I got the blue and yellow around
>   the wrong way? Any hex values that are
>   a de facto standard for these?"

At a basic level, within an existing design structure that is all blue, another panel that pops up in blue will be easily missed. If you are producing something within a brand color scheme and then force a 'correct' hierarchy of colors without consulting a designer, you won't be popular.

But UI design is far more complex than this. For instance, if a red message pops up every time you load a page, you'll start to ignore red messages because of their frequency.

It wouldn't hurt to read something entry-level like *Don't Make me Think* - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Think-Usability-Circle-Com/dp/0789723107, even if you're not really going to be doing this kind of decision-making often because it will help you understand the people who do.

Comment: Oh dear, I guess I sound a bit condescending then :( sorry.

Comment: I mainly asked this question to get some more info on the subject as I had never given it much thought. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A word of warning, Red/Green color-blindness is the most common form. So creating a UI that requires the user to distinguish them might get you into trouble.

Too bad no one thought about this when they developed traffic lights.

**Update:** Found this interesting article that gives you a workaround and explains better how red-green color blind people actually perceive these colors. Apparently by creating differences in saturation and brightness they CAN learn to distinguish the colors.

Its a good read: ["Red-green-color blindness doesn't mean you cant distinguish red from"](http://www.colblindor.com/2007/09/14/red-green-color-blindness-doesnt-mean-you-cant-distinguish-red-from-green/)

Comment: An icon representation along with the colour will approach the problem from both angles.

Comment: John: Good thing, then, that height can also be used when judging traffic lights.

Comment: Not just height. They always put the colors in the same order from top to bottom and left to right.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I just said. Though here in AUstralia are lights are top/down, not left/right.

Answer (score 1):

There are no standards for hex values to use. In most cases you will want to consider the choice in the context of the site or application. Try a range and you'll find one that sticks.

Colour can mean different things in different countries so you may want to consider alternatives if you need to support users in a country like China.

Answer (score 0):

Yellow usually means warning. Less important info might be gray text without any special icon or background color.

But ultimately it needs to make sense to your users.